# expand textarea when onFocus

Tags: javascript

I have number of textarea fileds and I want them all to expant when they are on focus

here is a demo of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/PU73y/

The issue is that they don't expand at the moment I click on them. why is that?

Thanks

```
<textarea id='txt1' class='txt' refID='1' style='height: 15px;'>this is testing of textrea  </textarea>


$(function() {
    $(".txt").focus(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
    //  alert(refID);

        $('#txt' + refID).focus (function() {
            $('#txt' + refID).animate({
                width: 400,
                height: 200
            }, 1000);
        });

        $('#txt' + refID).blur(function() {
            $('#txt' + refID).animate({
                width: 400,
                height: 20
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3rMM/

CSS...

```
.expand {
    height: 1em;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

HTML...

```
<textarea class="expand" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
```

jQuery...

```
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "4em" }, 500);
});
```

SOmething like this will work.

Comment: I had initial downvoted because it didn't really answer his issue - which was a nested click handler - have an upvote because i felt bad for downvoting

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this with CSS, no need for JavaScript:

```
textarea {
    height: 15px;
}

textarea:focus {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px; 
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PU73y/5/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PU73y/3/

you were setting a second focus handlers inside your initial focus handler, so you needed to click again to trigger that handler. All i did in this fiddle was remove the inner handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(".txt").focus(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var refID = element.attr("refID");
    //  alert(refID);


            $('#txt' + refID).animate({
                width: 400,
                height: 200
            }, 1000);


        $('#txt' + refID).blur(function() {
            $('#txt' + refID).animate({
                width: 400,
                height: 20
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/PU73y/4/

Your problem was you created the listeners on `$('#txt' + refID)` only *after* the first focus.